# PyCharm generating skeletons of 3rd party libraries

Tags: c#, ironpython, pycharm

I'm having a small problem with PyCharm 3.0.2 Community Edition generating a skeleton of a SQL library I've created in C# for use in an IronPython environment.

I'm trying to essentially get some nice intellisense for my library in PyCharm so I'm having it generate a skeleton of the binary file, however, that's where things go wrong.

The library is registered in the GAC as "SqlMagic.dll".

This is the namespace layout: SqlMagic.Monitor.Sql, and inside that last namespace is a class called Sql.

So, in IronPython, I have this code written:

```
from SqlMagic.Monitor.Sql import Sql
```

So PyCharm underlines SqlMagic and Sql at the very end. I tell it to generate stubs for the binary module, which it does! ...until I go look at the actual py file it generates:

```
# encoding: utf-8
# module SqlMagic.Monitor.Sql.Sql
# from None
# by generator 1.130
# Skeleton generation error:
#
#     Failed to process 'SqlMagic.Monitor.Sql.Sql' while importing: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\****\.PyCharm30\system\python_stubs\-2136665193\SqlMagic\Monitor\Sql\Sql.py' because it is being used by another process.
```

I'm significantly confused as to *why* this is raising a problem. I really don't know what else to do. I've tried using a different version of PyCharm, but that doesn't seem to resolve the issue (I still get this process failed error message).

Does anybody have any suggestions of help with this? I'm not sure what to even search. Heck, even a nudge in the right direction would be great!

Comment: Are you sure that you are running against IronPython and not CPython? Could you please look at the output of `import sys` `print (sys.version)` just to make sure and provide more info on your environment?

Comment: 2.7.3 (IronPython 2.7.3 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.18408 (32-bit))


Seems that I am targeting IronPython. I'm on Windows 7 64 bit "N". The location of the .py files is in C:\EPS\


Is that enough information @SimonOpelt ? If not, please do let me know :)

Comment: I was able to reproduce the behavior you are facing in PyCharm 3.0.2. In the latest preview (133.738) it fails without generating the files at all. You should probably file this as a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard/PY#tab=0 .

Comment: Thanks @SimonOpelt. I have filed [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11961).